# Anglular Transclude from child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I use to render a bootstrap panel, I use transclude to allow me to render custom content eg

```
<tn-Panel class="ng-cloak" title="'My Things'" >
    <tn-Thing>
    </tn-Thing>
</tn-Panel>
```

The tn-panel renders a header with the title and places the directive tn-thing within.

I would like to be able to render content in the body and some other content in the footer.

The following plunk shows this

https://plnkr.co/edit/j8U8MZlVSQCFB7RkpwOY?p=preview

But, it does not render the bits from content and header

```
  <pane title="Nested">
    <panenested></panenested> <-- does not following the transclude 
  </pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

updated your directive

```
  .directive('pane', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude:  {
        'content': '?content',  
        'footer': '?footer',
        'panenested':'?panenested',
    },
    scope: { title:'@' },
    template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                'Content : <br> <ng-transclude  ng-transclude="content"></ng-transclude> <br>' +
                'Footer : <br> <ng-transclude  ng-transclude="footer"></ng-transclude> <br>' 
                +'<br> <ng-transclude  ng-transclude="panenested"></ng-transclude> <br>'+
              '</div>'
  };
```

Comment: I want the contents of the conent element to render inside the slot for content eg `<div><content>test</content></div>` into `'Content : <br> <ng-transclude  ng-transclude="content"></ng-transclude> <br>' ` ofc just the text **test** rendered as Content : <br> **test**